# JS Console Variable Output Issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue running a bit of javascript I have made (converted from existing Google python code) to define a zoom level based on latitude and longitude values of a rectangle in a google map.  I am currently having an issue with the output of a couple variables.. I have attached an image showing the variables in question and their outputs using the `console.log()` command.

[image: Code error]

As you can see the `bottom_left` and `top_right` variables differ from their assignments `bounds[0]` and `bounds[1]` respectively.  I'm sure that I am doing something wrong here in this function, as the output is different from what I mean to assign the variables as.  I was also wondering why there is a problem when using `console.log(bottom_left)` or `console.log(top_right)` in the console?  Is it because these variables aren't globally defined?

Overall, the code fails to run *properly* as it outputs the maximum Zoom no matter what Lat / Long values are inputted (Theoretically the zoom level should get smaller and smaller with the increase in Lat / Long extents).

Below is the entire code from the sample:

```
//Define initial variables
var southWestLat = 10;
var southWestLng = -180;
var northEastLat = 60;
var northEastLng = -50;
var bounds = new Array ();
bounds[0] = new Array (southWestLat,southWestLng);
bounds[1] = new Array (northEastLat,northEastLng)
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//Point constructor
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
function CalcWrapWidth(zoom) {
  return pixel_range[zoom]
}
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
function range(lowEnd,highEnd){
    var arr = [],
    c = highEnd - lowEnd + 1;
    while ( c-- ) {
        arr[c] = highEnd--
    }
    return arr;
}
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
function Bound(value,opt_min,opt_max) {
  if (opt_min != null) {
    value = Math.max(value,opt_min);
  }
  if (opt_max != null) {
    value = Math.min(value,opt_max);
  }
  return value;
}
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//Converts from degrees to radians
function DegToRad(deg) {
  return deg*(Math.pi/180);
}
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//Gets center bounds, bounds as ['lat','lng']
function GetCenter(bounds) {
  var center_lat = (bounds[1][0] + bounds[0][0])/2;
  var center_lng = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1])/2;
  var center = new Array ();
  center[0] = center_lat;
  center[1] = center_lng;
  return center;
}
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//Prepare the calculation...
var pixels_per_lon_deg = new Array ();
var pixels_per_lon_rad = new Array ();
var pixel_origo = new Array ();
var pixel_range = new Array ();
var pixels = 640;
var zoom_levels = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];
var pointObj = new Array ();
var origin;
function prime() {
  for (i in zoom_levels) {
    origin = pixels/2;
    pixels_per_lon_deg.push(pixels/360);
    pixels_per_lon_rad.push(pixels/(2*Math.pi));
    pixel_origo.push({x:origin,y:origin});
    pixel_range.push(pixels);
    pixels = pixels*2;
  }
}

//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//Convert from Lat Lng to pixel
function FromLatLngToPixel(lat_lng, zoom) {
  o=pixel_origo[zoom];
  x_cord=Math.round(o.x+lat_lng[1]*pixels_per_lon_deg[zoom]);
  siny=Bound(Math.sin(DegToRad(lat_lng[0])),-0.9999,0.9999);
  y_cord=Math.round(o.y+0.5*Math.log((1+siny) / (1-siny))*-pixels_per_lon_rad[zoom]);
  pointObj = ({x:x_cord,y:y_cord}); //Potential error here?
  return pointObj
}
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
/**Main function bounds: A list of length 2, each holding a list of length 2. It holds
        the southwest and northeast lat/lng bounds of a map.  It should look 
        like this: [[southwestLat, southwestLng], [northeastLat, northeastLng]]**/
function CalculateBoundsZoomLevel(bounds) {
  var zmax=18;
  var zmin=0;
  var bottom_left=bounds[0];
  var top_right=bounds[1];
  var backwards_range=range(zmin,zmax).reverse();
  var lng_dsc = Math.abs(bounds[0][1] - bounds[1][1]);
  var lat_dsc = Math.abs(bounds[0][0] - bounds[1][0]);
  var rrun = lat_dsc/lng_dsc;
  var runr = lng_dsc/lat_dsc;
  var vs_height;
  var vs_length;
  console.log(bottom_left) //Delete
  console.log(top_right) //Delete
  if (rrun<1) {
    vs_height = 640*rrun;
    vs_length = 640;
  } else {
    vs_height = 640;
    vs_length = 640*runr;
  }
  var view_size = new Array (vs_length,vs_height);
  for (z in backwards_range) {
    var bottom_left_pixel=FromLatLngToPixel(bottom_left,z);
    var top_right_pixel=FromLatLngToPixel(top_right,z);
    if (bottom_left_pixel.x > top_right_pixel.x) {
      bottom_left_pixel.x -= CalcWrapWidth(z);
    }
    if (Math.abs(top_right_pixel.x - bottom_left_pixel.x) <= view_size[0] && Math.abs(top_right_pixel.y - bottom_left_pixel.y) <= view_size[1]) {
      return z
    }  
  }
  return 0
}
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//------------------------------------
//Run function 
prime()
CalculateBoundsZoomLevel([southWestLat,southWestLng],[northEastLat,northEastLng])
console.log(z)
```

As always any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You're calling `CalculateBoundsZoomLevel` with 2 arguments, but it only expects one argument. And the code expects `bounds` to be a 2-dimensional array, but it's just 1-dimensional.

Comment: The variable `bounds` inside the function is not the same as the global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple you are passing in two arguments to a function that expects one.

```
function CalculateBoundsZoomLevel(bounds) {
                                  ^^^^^^

CalculateBoundsZoomLevel([southWestLat,southWestLng],[northEastLat,northEastLng])
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I assume you wanted it to be a 2D array

```
CalculateBoundsZoomLevel([[southWestLat,southWestLng],[northEastLat,northEastLng]])
```

Comment: Wow I cannot believe I missed that... Thank you.  Unfortunately it still seems to be outputting the same zoom level for any lat / long pair, which I believe is a problem rooted in the `FromLatLngToPixel()` function.

Comment: It appears that 'pixels_per_lon_rad' is outputting NaN values.  It looks like it has something to do with the Math.pi function in the calculation, but I cannot figure out what is different about the Math.pi here than in the rest of the script...

Comment: I was typing `Math.PI` incorrectly as `Math.Pi`.  Unfortunately, it still looks like something is wrong as the code is only outputting 0 now.

Answer (score 0):

You have the function defined as:

```
function CalculateBoundsZoomLevel(bounds) {
```

So inside the function, the variable `bounds` is the first argument from the call

```
CalculateBoundsZoomLevel([southWestLat,southWestLng],[northEastLat,northEastLng])
```

So `bounds[0] == southWestLat` and `bounds[1] == southWestLng`. This isn't the same as when you use `console.log(bounds[0])` in the console. Then it's using the global variables that were defined with:

```
var bounds = new Array ();
bounds[0] = new Array (southWestLat,southWestLng);
bounds[1] = new Array (northEastLat,northEastLng)
```

The global `bounds` array is a 2-dimensional array, but inside the function it's just a 1-dimensional array.

You should use:

```
CalculateBoundsZoomLevel(bounds)
```

to use the same array inside the function as outside.